# Adding pdf as hyperlink for point in QGIS and GVSIG?

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, pdf, hyperlink, gvsig

I am working on a project for which I would have to make a map displaying all archaeological sites of the city; it will later be used and accessed by my office's stuff only. In the end, when clicking on each site, the user should be able to see all the site's information displayed in a dialogue box, but also he should be able to see and have access to the site's relative documents (one pdf for each site). Till now, they have been using gvsig, and some of them insist that we continue working with it, although I have the possibility to choose between that and QGIS.

In any case, I know neither to that level (i am a beginner in QGIS and never worked with GVSIG) so would you indicate me which of the two programs is better for what I want?

And then, could anyone tell me a simple and easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Both QGIS and gvSIG support hyperlinks. Generally you need a text field containing the path of the PDF document and then set the hyperlink field in the layer properties.

- Example in QGIS: http://youtu.be/CUxkddOP3BQ
- Example in gvSIG: http://youtu.be/4hW6VUwXU4M

Answer (score 0):

And if you have several PDF files asociated to the same point... in the last version of gvSIG (gvSIG 2.2) you can add a folder as hyperlink (http://blog.gvsig.org/2015/05/18/gvsig-2-2-hyperlink-to-folders/)